# Microsoft.Online.DirectoryServices.DirectoryValueExistsException on trying to add users to office 365 group (AzureAD)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft365

I tried to add a bulk of users into M365 group. However, the group contains 0 members. On checking the logs, I see that a lot of member adds were successful to the group and the ones that did log a failure were all for the following reason: Microsoft.Online.DirectoryServices.DirectoryValueExistsException. That was the sole reported reason for any failures to add members to that group. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I try to follow these [steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/groups-bulk-import-members) to add group members in bulk in Azure Active Directory.

**csv file:**

[image]

**result:**

[image]

Please check your `Bulk operation results` and share the `Failure reason` of the user.

[image]